# When I'm Using "sudo apt update" I'm getting

Tags: apt, updates, sudo

```
sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://your.repo.domain/repository bionic InRelease
  Could not resolve 'your.repo.domain'
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                                                                                              
Hit:3 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease                                                                                                      



Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease           
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you removed the actual repository and replaced it with a custom one, but the first one (assuming that's what you have set up) is not a real repository.

You can remove the repository in one of the following ways:

- software sources
- removing the line for the repository from `/etc/apt/sources.list`
- if it's not in the above file, look in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory for the ppa and remove the appropriate file (you could use the `rm` command to remove a specific file, but be careful not to delete something you don't want to delete... if you're new, create a test directory and try using the `rm` command to delete files from it to verify you don't delete the wrong thing, also avoid using `sudo` when practicing the command to avoid removing important files)

As for the security related issue, I'll need to know which version of ubuntu you have (I'll edit the answer accordingly)